# How to get all rows along with column names as first row

Tags: mysql, sql

With a single query how to get all rows of a table along with column names. So that my first row will contain column names.
How to do it in mysql.I want to use the results in my node application

Update:
I am working on application which I am doing on node js.I have a requirement  where I have to display my entire table view in my UI. If I use select * from table name I will get only rows as results.I need  another call to get the column names also. I am just checking whether we can do same with single query,So that I can get everything in a single call to mysql from node.js

Comment: I hope you aren't asking about the select * statement

Comment: My scenario is when I use select * from table name; I will get only rows of the table in my node(JavaScript on server side) app,but I need column names as well in the first row

Comment: Why don't you run 2 queries, 1 selecting the `column_name`, 1 selecting the whole table.

Comment: There would be some ways in node js framework from which you can get the column names, otherwise how will it map the data, I think this wont be the appropriate way of doing it. Not sure though

Comment: I am not good at my SQL.Just want yo know can we do that in mysql?

Comment: @Surya have you tried `desc table_name` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the droid you are looking for, but try out this:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='table'
```

Also Check [INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html)

Another thing you could try is to show field names:

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM table;
```

Comment: The above query only returns column names .But my scenario is I want all the rows as well

Answer (score 1):

If you know the column names, you could use a simple UNION:

```
SELECT 'firstname', 'lastname' UNION
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM people
```

Result:

```
+----+-----------+-------------+
|    | firstname |  lastname   |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | firstname | lastname    |
|  2 | Kenny     | Rogers      |
|  3 | Dolly     | Parton      |
|  4 | Michael   | Jackson     |
|  5 | Donald    | Trump       |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```

**DEMO:** http://rextester.com/TYOD33589

If you do not know the column names you could use [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to select all column names in a specified table, and concatenate them into a string that can be executed in a query:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT CONCAT("'", GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY ordinal_position SEPARATOR "', '"), "'") 
  INTO @sql
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema = 'databasename' AND table_name = 'people';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' UNION SELECT * FROM people');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**DEMO:** http://rextester.com/NRWP39999

Note: Replace `databasename` with the name of your database and `people` with the name of your table in the above statement.

Answer (score -6):

If I got your question right this can help you

```
Select * from table_name;
```

Thanks!